# Issue with <xpm:init> tag

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t, 2013-sp1

I'm new to this Tridion and DD4T development and I need some help on XPM.

We're currently doing a POC using DD4T version 2.0.2. We are trying to implement inline html editor using XPM tag.

The view and editable tags seem to be fine (They're outputting json in the HTML if we view source) but if we add `<xpm:init page="${pageModel}" />` before the `</body>` then it stops rendering at that point and no JSON is output for the page.

Could someone please tell me if I did something wrong or confirm that the `<xpm:init>` tag works in the version 2.0.2?

dd4t.properties

```
xpm.enabled=true
xpm.cmsUrl=http://1.2.3.4/
```

Here is the code:

[image]

Comment: You should see an Exception in the logs somewhere. Can you post that?

Comment: There were a couple of bugs in the implementation. These are now fixed. See https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/issues/44. Release 2.0.5 is expected shortly.

Comment: Hi Raimond, it seems that you fixed the issue already so I don't need to post the logs. Do you know the schedule for 2.0.5 release? Thanks

Comment: I need to run some tests, but other than that it's ready for release. Expect something this weekend.

Comment: Hi Rainmond, I just created another issue. I'm not sure if this relate to the other one. Could you take a look? <http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/14117/xpm-tag-itemnotfoundexception-unable-to-find-page-by-url> Thanks

Comment: Commented in the other question :)

Answer (score 1):

From comment:

> There were a couple of bugs in the implementation. These are now fixed. See https://github.com/dd4t/dd4t-2-java/issues/44. Release 2.0.5 is expected shortly.